# Binding inside the ItemsPanelTemplate from Parent in Windows phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7.1, itemspaneltemplate

I want to change the Orientation of StackPanel which is inside the ItemsPanelTemplate... To change the Orientation i have implemented one property.. Is there any way to change the orientation of StackPanel. I tried the following code.. But it is not succeeded.

```
<Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <StackPanel Orientation="{Binding MyOrientation,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `{RelativeSource AncestorType=YourItemsControlType}`

**MyItemsControl.cs:**

```
namespace MyNamespace.Controls
{
    public partial class MyItemsControl : ItemsControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MyOrientationProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
            "MyOrientation",
            typeof(Orientation),
            typeof(MyItemsControl));

        public Orientation MyOrientation
        {
            get { return (Orientation)GetValue(MyOrientationProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MyOrientationProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

**MyItemsControls.xaml**

```
<Style xmlns:source="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.Controls" TargetType="source:MyItemsControl">
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel 
                    Orientation="{Binding Orientation, 
                        RelativeSource={
                            RelativeSource AncestorType=source:MyItemsControl
                        }
                    }"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Reference:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743599%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[RelativeSource.TemplatedParent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource.templatedparent.aspx) is for `ControlTemplates`.

Refer some samples [here](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/working-with-itemspanel-in-wp7)

Comment: I want to change the orientation of the StackPanel which is inside of the ItemsPanelTemplate..But the post which you given is not helped me... sorry..

Comment: samples to give some idea to use this, not exactly for your queries.. so that i told, refer sample.